# Can't get google font to work

Tags: html, css, import, fonts, google-fonts

I have looked through other peoples answers to the question and followed the instructions on google and just cannot get it to work. Here is what I have used.

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Archivo+Black|Playfair+Display:400,700i,900');
```

The worst part is that Playfiar Display is working fine, Archivo is not at all.

For reference, georgialee.design is the URL. (works on every browser except for internet explorer)

Thank you so much! I'm sure it'll be some silly mistake :)

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What is not working?

Comment: The font Archivo Black

Answer (score 1):

Copy this code into the < head > of your HTML document:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Archivo+Black" rel="stylesheet">
```

In your CSS file, use the following rule to set the font-family:

```
// if you only want to change h1 fonts, use this selector
h1 { 
    font-family: 'Archivo Black', sans-serif;
}
```

For example:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Archivo+Black" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display" rel="stylesheet">
 <style>
  // default font for everything in the body
  body {
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  }

  // make all h1 Archivo 
  // note: if you want h2, h3 etc to be archivo as well you need to add the respective selector
  body h1 {
    font-family: 'Archivo Black', sans-serif;
  }
 </style>
</head>
 <body>
  <div>rest of your page...</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

[see more examples here](https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/getting_started)

[see here to find out more about css selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: I just tried this, when i did it both fonts stopped working

Comment: Does it have to be "body"? as the font is only used for H1

Comment: Hi Georiga, if you use body then all the fonts will be changed... you basically are using a css selector and applying that font to them. so if you only want to change the h1, you need to use a selector for h1, I have update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In header section you import it

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Archivo+Black" rel="stylesheet">
```

or

```
<style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Archivo+Black');
</style>
```

In style.css file

```
body{
    font-family: 'Archivo Black', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: I still couldn't get it to work, Playfair works and Archivo still wont

Comment: try this <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Archivo+Black|Playfair+Display:400,400i,700,700i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">
body section import both fonts
font-family: 'Playfair Display', 'Archivo Black', serif, sans-serif ;